# Select All options using React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using [React Select](https://react-select.com/home). I would like to select all options when I click `Select All`. My `jsx` code is like below.

```
<Select
    options={postValues}
    placeholder={"Select Post"}
    className="modal__input"
    isMulti={true}
    name={"post_id"}
    onChange={handlePostChange}
/>
```

My `postValues` array is like below.

```
let postValues = [];
  let val_post = {};
  if (postList?.data) {
    postValues.push({ label: "Select All", value: "select_all" });    
    postList.data.map((post) => {
      val_post = { label: post.name, value: post.id };
      postValues.push(val_post);
      return postValues;
    });
  }
```

My `handlePostChange` function is like below.

```
const handlePostChange = (options) => {
    const postArray = [];
    options.map((option) => {
      if (option.value == 'select_all') {
        postValues = postValues.splice(1, (postValues.length - 1));
        postValues.map((option) => postArray.push(option.value));
      } else {
        postArray.push(option.value);
      }
    });

    setState({
      post_id: postArray,
    });
  };
```

But All Options are not selecting when I click on `Select All`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the selected item is an object not a string value:

```
const handlePostChange = (options) => {
    const postArray = [];
    options.map((option) => {
      if (option.value == 'select_all') {
        postValues = postValues.splice(1, (postValues.length - 1));
        postValues.map((option) => postArray.push(option));
      } else {
        postArray.push(option);
      }
    });

    setState({
      post_id: postArray,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the value prop

```
<Select
    options={postValues}
    placeholder={"Select Post"}
    className="modal__input"
    isMulti={true}
    name={"post_id"}
    onChange={handlePostChange}
    value={state.post_id}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ingenious_Hans. Now I am getting this output. https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6ygz.png